# Need suggestions to make the ipad application sections easier for the user

Tags: user-expectation, ipad

I have an iPad application, please see the attached image for the rough mockup of the screens.

Basically, the landing page is a language sector which is designed as language labels with a check mark to show the selected language

The second screen is a simple form, (I've removed the fields not related to this question) where we have a simple Yes/No question.
I opted for the standard IOS switch along with the textual representation, which would be "Yes/No" equivalents for the languages on the landing page.

I need to make both these sections as easy and obvious as possible for the  end users.

[image: Rough Mockup of the screens]

Comment: I think you need a designer, not sure what the UX question is here

Comment: hi devin, we have actually designed it as per the mock above, however, the feedback was, this is not user-friendly and a bit difficult for non-tech savvy users..
so I basically wanted a general opinion as for how should these sections be laid out...
I browsed through some options like https://usersnap.com/blog/design-language-switch/ but could not get a definitive answer

Comment: For the style and position of the switch see how Apple uses it in settings.

Answer (score 2):

For iPad App it would be **best to use the Operating Systems default language for your application, because that option is chosen by the user while setting up his device** (This logic works best when majority of your target users use same language ). So the first screen is not needed at all.

Start your application with the Yes/No form, but try to **place the Switch button on right side because we read English left to right**.